# ViewPager does not respect order inside LinearLayout

Tags: android

I have this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/blanco"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/verde_us" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/detalle_imagen_categoria"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_map" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/View02"
                    android:layout_width="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@color/blanco" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_nombre_empresa"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/text_noticias"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/blanco" />
            </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

But when I run the app the output is other.

Any help? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: The output is that ViewPager covering whole screen?

Comment: Can you be any more specific about how you expect it to look? It is not immediately apparent to me looking at your screenshot and XML file why it's wrong

Comment: *ViewPager does not respect order inside LinearLayout* yes, it does ... prolly you are using wrong tabs ... (on actionbar?)

Comment: why is your viewPager has __match_parent__ height?

Comment: Agreed. The layout you are asking for appears to be what you are getting, assuming that the Ahumadero content is in the `ViewPager`. The preview will not show action bar tabs, in part because the preview does not know about them, and in part because action bar tabs were deprecated in Android 5.0.

Comment: @FoamyGuy I want the tabs below the text that says "Ahumadero"

In the XML file the LL is first and in the device is the tabs, first.

Comment: @commonsware the "Ahumadero" is in the same XML where is the viewPager. I want "Ahumadero" first and then the viewPager.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the tabs below the text that says "Ahumadero" In the XML

Then stop using action bar tabs. Use some other sort of tabbed indicator for your `ViewPager`, one where you control the position by placing it in the `LinearLayout` yourself. There are many open source implementations, such as `PagerSlidingTabStrip`.

Comment: Ok, I will try and comment.